# Android SeekBar's progressBackgroundTint has no effect in API v21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, seekbar

I'm noticing that when changing my SeekBar's progressBackgroundTint attribute, it gets completely ignored and has no effect. It doesn't matter what color I set it to; it always shows as gray on my device. Is this a bug with Android, or am I doing something wrong? When I switch the preview in Android Studio to v22, it gets properly set. But not so on v21.

My seekbar:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#ff4babe8"/>
```

I also tried setting progressBackgroundTintMode to all the known values, but still no effect. Anyone know why?

Comment: Your hex color has 2 too many characters... 8 instead of 6.

Comment: @MikePurcell: The first hex byte (FF) is the alpha value. See e.g. [android.graphics.Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). So problem is not there.

Comment: May be it only work for device with OS lollipop or greater

Answer (score 2):

Try this library. 
It works great simple
https://github.com/ahmedrizwan/SeekBarCompat

Answer (score 0):

try using android:progressTint along with android:progressBackgroundTint

```
<ProgressBar
     android:progress="100"
     android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/buttonPrimary"
     android:progressTint="@color/buttonPrimary"
     android:id="@+id/progressBar"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: It is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this issue and then found out that the material components provide a `Slider` that works pretty much the same way and doesn't have this issue. Check out details here https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider